# Attempt to use the open() function failing

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu

I'm trying to learn to manipulate files on python, but I can't get the open function to work. I have made a .txt file called foo that holds the content "hello world!" in my user directory (/home/yonatan) and typed this line into the shell:

```
open('/home/yonatan/foo.txt')
```

What i get in return is:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='/home/yonatan/foo.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

I get what that means, but why don't I get the content?

Comment: could you post your whole code? and are you using `read()`? take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: f = open('/home/yonatan/foo.txt', 'r'); f.read()

Comment: @mattR its one line i ran through the shell. i don't have anything else. i didn't try to use read. trying to get open to work before moving on.

Comment: This should be explained in practically any Python tutorial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`open()` returns a file object.

You then need to use `read()` to read the whole file

```
f = open('/home/yonatan/foo.txt', 'r')
contents = f.read()
```

Or you can use `readline()` to read just one line

```
line = f.readline()
```

and don't forget to close the file at the end

```
f.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

An example iterating through the lines of the file (*using* `with` *which ensures* `file.close()` *gets called on the end of it's lexical scope*):

```
file_path = '/home/yonatan/foo.txt'
with open(file_path) as file:
    for line in file:
        print line
```

A great [resource](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) on I/O and file handling operations.

Answer (score -4):

You haven't specified the mode you want to open it in.

Try:

```
f = open("home/yonatan/foo.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

Comment: tried it and it didn't work. every place i've seen says that you shouldn't have to, and it kinda makes sense since the output does say `mode= 'r'`.

Comment: if person said that he learns to manipulate you don't provide example of open without close - it will not teach anything good him; as well prefer using with open to avoid this error

Comment: this does the same thing the op did; his even opened in mode r; the answers by moboto and sembei are much more useful

Comment: @Drako ok i am sorry, i am just learning too, i only try to help.